# What is the best search algorithm for the missionaries and cannibals?

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence

I was thinking it'd be depth first search (but this might get stuck in a loop) so I think it isn't the best algorithm for this. Would a*, uniform cost,... or does breath-first-search have a chance to be the best search algorithm for this?

Comment: Any search algorithm which keeps track of visited states (thus avoiding loops) should do.

Comment: yeah but which is the best?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what you are measuring. Possible measures are running time, nodes expanded/generated, implementation complexity, or others.

I would suggest using breadth-first search (BFS) because it is the simplest to implement and this particular problem is small enough that it can be solved nearly instantly even by BFS.

Also, it is very important to note that BFS is not the same as A* with a zero-heuristic. BFS can terminate as soon as the goal is generated while A* terminates when the goal is removed from OPEN for expansion. Also, A* needs much more complicated data structures that will be harder to implement, while BFS can use a simple FIFO queue.